# Where in iTunes Connect can I upload my large image icon?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an app that is already in the App Store. I am providing an update to the app and want to change the large icon. For some reason it still shows the old app icon. There are no options to upload a new 512x512 icon. Where can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTunes Connect → Manage Your Apps → (Your App) → Current Version - View Details → Uploads - Edit

Comment: I can modify my screenshots, but for some reason I am unable to "edit" the large icon, there is no button for it..

Comment: Now as you mention it, I noticed that the upload button that I thought was for the icon was actually for iPhone screenshots (I looked at an iPad app). You could try to change the "iTunesArtwork" file in your update (see here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html) but it should actually only be used for AdHoc builds so I'm not sure if this would have any effect...

Comment: It could also be that you can only change this while you're submitting an update. It used to be this way for screenshots too.

Comment: I am submitting an update. It is in developer release mode right now. I need to change the image

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would update this as this has now changed.

As per https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=1092013a

> Beginning January 9, app screenshots will be locked in iTunes Connect once your app has been approved. New screenshots may be uploaded when you submit a binary for an update to an existing app or a new app

So you can no longer update any images unless you are providing a new binary for upload as well at which point you can do

iTunesConnect --> Manage Your Apps --> (Your App) --> New Version - View Details --> Uploads - Edit